# Forcing form to go website.com/test/ instead of website.com?name=

Tags: php, html

So im trying to create a search for a name but when i click the sumbit button it goes to websitelink.com?=name=Nighel but i want it to go like this websitelink.com/Nighel/

Yes i'm already using htacces thats why the ?= doesnt work for me

I cant seem to figure out how to sort this out.

This is for searching based on name in my logs

What i use for grabbing the name

```
            $name = isset($_GET['playername']) ? $_GET['playername'] : "";

            <div class="ironman-nav">
                <form>
                    <span class="ironman-nav__option">Search for username</span>
                    <input class="ironman-nav__option" type="text" name="playername" placeholder="Username..." autocomplete="off">
                    <input class="ironman-nav__option" type="submit" value="Submit">
                </form>
            </div>
```

Comment: post your htaccess code

Comment: RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?page=$1&action=$2&id=$3&playername=$4

Thats the one im using for that page.

Comment: post the code in your question

Comment: @JosanIracheta I am not able to post everything, but here is the $name stuff

<?php
$page = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : 0;
$name = isset($_GET['playername']) ? $_GET['playername'] : "";
echo "<span style='color:white;'>name - " . $name. "</span>";

if (!is_numeric($page) || $page < 1)
  $page = 0;

?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this with javascript changing dynamically the form action attribute with the input value when a key is pressed over it or before submit the form.

Comment: Thank you so much, i totally forgot about javascript, with javascript its really easy.

Answer (score 0):

The client side is not aware of your server rewrite rule

For the client `test` in `website.com/test/` is just part of the URL, so if you want the browser to submit the form to `website.com/test/` then set the action attribute of the form as `website.com/test/`

if you want the `test` part to be variable then you have to build the URL of the form dynamically. something like this

```
<div class="ironman-nav">
    <form  action="https://website.com/<?=$name?>">
        <span>Search for username</span>
        <input type="text" name="playername">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is that the $_GET['playername'] isnt set so $name is empty

Comment: you can set a default value if the client didn't provide `$_GET['playername']`  for example `!isset( $_GET['playername']) ?  $_GET['playername'] = "defaultName" : "";`

Answer (score 0):

I'll break down my response into two parts, the first explaining the behavior of the original code, and the second will contain possible implementation routes.

HTML forms, by default, will take collate all the input tags (`<input>`, `<textarea>`, `<select>`, etc) as a dictionary, where the key is the node's name (the attribute) and the value is the node's value (also the attribute).

So in your case,

```
$name = isset($_GET['playername']) ? $_GET['playername'] : "";

<div class="ironman-nav">
    <form>
        <span class="ironman-nav__option">Search for username</span>
            <input class="ironman-nav__option" type="text" name="playername" placeholder="Username..." autocomplete="off">
            <input class="ironman-nav__option" type="submit" value="Submit">
     </form>
</div>
```

Will do the following, on submit:

1. Create a dictionary containing the following key-value pairs: playername=VALUE_FROM_PLAYERNAME_INPUT
2. Make a GET request to the current page with the above parameters: GET /thispage?playername=VALUE_FROM_PLAYERNAME_INPUT

Since you wanted the request to go to /thispage/VALUE_FROM_PLAYERNAME_INPUT instead, you will need to modify the submission event handler for that form. Unfortuneatly it appears that Accountant م's won't worry for you since you don't have the target username at the time the search page is loaded (so the action attribute of the form tag cannot be pre-populated with the target user).

```
var searchForm = document.querySelector('.ironman-nav form');
searchForm.addEventListener('submit', function(evt) {
    searchForm.action = '' + searchForm.querySelector('input[name="playername"]').value;
});
```

The reason I put an empty string in the search form action is in case you needed to prefix the action URL with anything. For example, if your search page and results page was called `search.html`, then `searchForm.action = 'search.html' + searchForm.querySelector('input[name="playername"]').value;`. You have to do this because it is a relative URL (action URL does not begin with a protocol or slash), and as such the browser will search for that resource starting from the parent of the current page.